# Trouble reading text from a pdf in Perl

Tags: perl, pdf

I am trying to read the text content of a pdf file into a Perl variable. From other SO questions/answers I get the sense that I need to use `CAM::PDF`. Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CAM::PDF;
my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new('1950-01-01.pdf');
print $pdf->numPages(), " pages\n\n";

my $text = $pdf->getPageText(1);
print $text, "\n";
```

I tried running this on [this pdf file](http://www.hawes.com/1950/1950-01-01.pdf). There are no errors reported by Perl. The first print statement works; it prints "2 pages" which is the correct number of pages in this document.

The next print statement does not return anything readable. Here's what the output looks like in Emacs:

```
2 pages

^A^B^C^D^E^C^F^D^G^H
^D^A^K^L^C^M^D^N^C^M^O^D^P^C^Q^Q^C      ^D^R^K^M^O^D ^A^B^C^D^E
^F^G^G^H^E
^K^L
^M^N^E^O^P^E^O^Q^R^S^E
.... more lines with similar codes ....
```

Is there something I can do to make this work? I don't understand pdf files too well, but I thought that because I can easily copy and paste the text from the PDF file using Acrobat, it must be recognized as text and not an image, so I hoped this meant I could extract it with Perl.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDFs can have different kinds of content. A PDF may not have any readable text at all, only bitmaps and graphical content, for example. The PDF you linked to, has compressed data in it. Open it with a text editor, and you will see that the content is in a "/Filter/FlateDecode" block. Perhaps [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/~cdolan/CAM-PDF-1.57/lib/CAM/PDF.pm) doesn't support that. Google FlateDecode for a few ideas.

Looking further into that PDF, i see that it also uses embedded subsets of fonts, with custom encodings. Even if CAM::PDF handles the compression, the custom encoding may be what's throwing it off. This may help: [Web page from a software company, describing the problem](http://www.glyphandcog.com/textext.html)

Comment: Ok. If I open the file in Acrobat, and save as a text file, it correctly exports the text. Because of that I assumed there must be some way to extract it with Perl. But is the difference that Acrobat understands the encoding and CAM::PDF doesn't?

Comment: Yes, i believe that's it. See the page i hyperlinked above, it describes what subset encoding looks like. There isn't any guaranteed way to recover what the characters are, other than rendering them and doing OCR (although some heuristics may work, as described in the part titled "Figuring it out").

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain that the issue isn't with your perl code, it is with the PDF file.  I ran the same script on one of my own PDF files, and it works just fine.